# Why IF checking ignores "^<delimter>some_word" after the check expression?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd

Here's the example:

```
@echo off
:: check syntax ignores "^<delimiter>something" right after check expression
if defined path^ blah echo #
if exist c:\^ blah echo #
if errorlevel 0^ blah echo #
:: but in comparison operations escaping works well
if 1^ blah==1^ blah echo #
```

Comment: With `@echo ON` you could see all results of parsing & what goes to execute exactly... For instance, `if defined path^ blah echo #` results to `if defined path echo #`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because that is how it works ;-)

In my opinion it is a design flaw with the IF command. The IF command has complicated (multiple phase) parsing rules, and I think MicroSoft dropped the ball a bit.

Escape does not work with IF EXIST or IF DEFINED. The first parsing pass properly identifies the condition and command, but the actual comparison stops at the first white space.

Quotes work with IF EXIST. But quotes do not help with IF DEFINED because they are considered to be part of the variable name.

The only way to get it to work properly in all cases is to use a FOR variable or delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "var=%%%%~A"

:: Start with a clean slate
set "a="
set "a z="
del "a" "a z" 2>nul

:: ---------- test escape --------------
:: This fails
set "a z=1"
if defined a^ z (
  echo if defined a^^ z TRUE  = SUCCESS
) else (
  echo if defined a^^ z FALSE = FAILURE
)
set "a z="

:: This fails
copy nul "a z" >nul
if exist a^ z (
  echo if exist a^^ z   TRUE  = SUCCESS
) else (
  echo if exist a^^ z   FALSE = FAILURE
)
del "a z"

:: This fails (looks at the wrong variable)
set "a=1"
if defined a^ z (
  echo if defined a^^ z TRUE  = FAILURE
) else (
  echo if defined a^^ z FALSE = SUCCESS
)
set "a="

:: This fails (looks at wrong file)
copy nul "a" >nul
if exist a^ z (
  echo if exist a^^ z   TRUE  = FAILURE
) else (
  echo if exist a^^ z   FALSE = SUCCESS
)
del "a"

echo(

:: ---------- test quotes --------------
:: This fails
set "a z=1"
if defined "a z" (
  echo if defined "a z" TRUE  = SUCCESS
) else (
  echo if defined "a z" FALSE = FAILURE
)
set "a z="

:: This succeeds
copy nul "a z" >nul
if exist "a z" (
  echo if exist "a z"   TRUE  = SUCCESS
) else (
  echo if exist "a z"   FALSE = FAILURE
)
del "a z"

:: This fails (looks at the wrong variable with quotes in name)
set ""a z"=1"
if defined "a z" (
  echo if defined "a z" TRUE  = FAILURE
) else (
  echo if defined "a z" FALSE = SUCCESS
)
set ""a z"="

:: This succeeds
copy nul "a" >nul
if exist "a z" (
  echo if exist "a z"   TRUE  = FAILURE
) else (
  echo if exist "a z"   FALSE = SUCCESS
)
del "a"

echo(

:: ---------- test FOR variable --------------
:: This succeeds
set "a z=1"
for %%A in ("a z") do if defined %%~A (
  echo if defined !var! TRUE  = SUCCESS
) else (
  echo if defined !var! FALSE = FAILURE
)
set "a z="

:: This succeeds
copy nul "a z" >nul
for %%A in ("a z") do if exist %%~A (
  echo if exist !var!   TRUE  = SUCCESS
) else (
  echo if exist !var!   FALSE = FAILURE
)
del "a z"

:: This succeeds
set "a=1"
for %%A in ("a z") do if defined %%~A (
  echo if defined !var! TRUE  = FAILURE
) else (
  echo if defined !var! FALSE = SUCCESS
)
set "a="

:: This succeeds
copy nul "a" >nul
for %%A in ("a z") do if exist %%~A (
  echo if exist !var!   TRUE  = FAILURE
) else (
  echo if exist !var!   FALSE = SUCCESS
)
del "a"

echo(

:: ---------- test delayed expansion --------------
set "var=a z"

:: This succeeds
set "a z=1"
if defined !var! (
  echo if defined ^^!var^^! TRUE  = SUCCESS
) else (
  echo if defined ^^!var^^! FALSE = FAILURE
)
set "a z="

:: This succeeds
copy nul "a z" >nul
if exist !var! (
  echo if exist ^^!var^^!   TRUE  = SUCCESS
) else (
  echo if exist ^^!var^^!   FALSE = FAILURE
)
del "a z"

:: This succeeds
set "a=1"
if defined !var! (
  echo if defined ^^!var^^! TRUE  = FAILURE
) else (
  echo if defined ^^!var^^! FALSE = SUCCESS
)
set "a="

:: This succeeds
copy nul "a" >nul
if exist !var! (
  echo if exist ^^!var^^!   TRUE  = FAILURE
) else (
  echo if exist ^^!var^^!   FALSE = SUCCESS
)
del "a"
```

--OUTPUT--

```
if defined a^ z FALSE = FAILURE
if exist a^ z   FALSE = FAILURE
if defined a^ z TRUE  = FAILURE
if exist a^ z   TRUE  = FAILURE

if defined "a z" FALSE = FAILURE
if exist "a z"   TRUE  = SUCCESS
if defined "a z" TRUE  = FAILURE
if exist "a z"   FALSE = SUCCESS

if defined %%~A TRUE  = SUCCESS
if exist %%~A   TRUE  = SUCCESS
if defined %%~A FALSE = SUCCESS
if exist %%~A   FALSE = SUCCESS

if defined !var! TRUE  = SUCCESS
if exist !var!   TRUE  = SUCCESS
if defined !var! FALSE = SUCCESS
if exist !var!   FALSE = SUCCESS
```

Comment: That's an exhaustive explanation how to check for variables or files with delimiters in their names , but the strange is the IF checks the condition before the caret and does not make an attempt to execute `^ blah` and jumps to the `echo`.The ` blah` is not reported as an error neither during the parsing nor in the execution...

Comment: Ok.I think I get it a little bit more.The IF has at least two phases of parsing.And the one with the bigger priority is to decide which part is the command to execute.

Comment: @npocmaka - Yes. We had a discussion about this at DosTips somewhere, but I can't find it.

Comment: This also works: `set a" "z=1` & `if defined a" "z ...` I use this form to define array elements with subscripts that may be any string with no quotes: `set key["%index%"]=1` so it is very easy to check if a given key was defined: `if defined key["%theSearchKey%"] ...` **Edit**: The changes in this site now prohibits to post a +1 at beginning of a comment!

Answer (score 3):

Why?
I don't know.

But It seems that the tokenizer executes two times in this cases.

Here is an example to show that the tokenizer is independent of the interim output of `ECHO ON`

```
echo ON
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var=hello you"
if !var! == hello^ you echo true
if !var! == hello you echo true
```

Both lines are shown as `if !var! == hello you echo true` but only the first executes the `echo true`, as there `hello you` is one token but not in the second sample.

```
set var=1
IF defined var^ bang echo VAR is defined
```

But as dbenham explains, the `IF DEFINED` and the `If EXIST` seems to tokenize it first as expected, as the second word will not be used as a command, but it's completly dropped.

The interessting effect is that a FOR parameter and delayed expansion aren't affected, although these phases are following directly the *echo phase*.

So I assume, that there is used another tokenizer by `IF defined` and `IF EXIST` in contrast to `IF .. <compare>`.

With `ECHO ON` (as JosefZ mentioned) you can see the differences.

```
if !var! == hello^ you echo true
if defined hello^ you echo is defined
```

Output

```
C:\temp>if !var! == hello you echo true
C:\temp>if defined hello echo is defined
```

In the first case the `hello you` is complete, but in the second sample the `you` was dropped.