# Why does the error message appear when `IF` comparison is in the piped block command?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, cmd, io-redirection

I simplified the code.
The following three are work.

```
for /L %a in (1,1,9) do @(if %a NEQ 0 (echo %a))
```

&

```
for /L %a in (1,1,9) do @(if not %a == 0 (echo %a))
```

&

```
(for /L %a in (1,1,9) do @(if not %a == 0 (echo %a)))|sort /R
```

But the next one didn't work,

```
(for /L %a in (1,1,9) do @(if %a NEQ 0 (echo %a)))|sort /R
```

What's the problem of `NEQ` in the piped block command?

more simplified,

This works, `(if 3 == 3 echo yes)|sort`

This doesn't work, `(if 3 NEQ 2 echo yes)|sort`

Part of my code.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Unx_path=.....\bin\UnxUtils\
(
for /F %%a in ('^""%Unx_path%pclip.exe"^|"%Unx_path%sed.exe" -r "s/^^$/none/"^|"%Unx_path%sed.exe" -rf "script_file"^"') do @(
  if not "%%a" == "none" (
    "%Unx_path%grep.exe" -iEe "%%a" "file4search"|"%Unx_path%sed.exe" -r "s/^^[^,]+$/,&/";"s/^^([^.]+)[.][^.]+$/\1/"|"%Unx_path%gawk.exe" "BEGIN{FS=\",\";ORS=\" \"}{print $2}"|"%Unx_path%sed.exe" "s/%%a//I g";"s/.*/%%a &|/";"s/ -/ /g";"s/ |/\n/g";"s/ /\t/g";"s/~/\t/g"
  ) else (
    echo none
  )
)
)|"%Unx_path%gclip.exe"
exit /b
```

Comment: [check this](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5539)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
set "myline=if 3 NEQ 2 echo yes"

( %myLin^e%)|sort
```

or from batch file (double expansion works differently from batch file and the console):

```
set "myline=if 3 NEQ 2 echo yes"

( %%myLine%%)|sort
```

The "mystery" was solved by jeb [here](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5539&start=15) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185370/what-happens-with-if-command-when-i-pipe-to-it) . Though you are facing the issue before the pipe it is the same bug because the cmd creates two threads on each side of the pipe.

Here's how the for loop can be made to work:

```
set "line=if %a NEQ 0"
(for /L %a in (1,1,9) do @( %lin^e% echo %a))|sort /R
```

Comment: Yes. That works. But I have complicated code `(for .... do @(if ... () else ()))|more`, which seems cannot be changed to that way.

Comment: @enjoying I think you can use the same technique. with for command.I'll try it and if I succeed will update the answer.

Comment: npocmaka, I added my part of code at the end of my question. It quite complicated. The solution you said is a exactly good one. But with my real code, I have to use `if not "..." == "..."` (Luckily, I don't need `LSS`, `GTR`, `GEQ` nor `LEQ` here.)

Comment: I found a way by testing the metod calling `%cmdcmdline%` from jeb . `echo pipe|if 1234^  gtr 124 echo %^cmdcmdline%` can work. One caret and two SPACEs have to be added before `gtr` due to the strange swallowing.

Comment: @enjoying -Ha! Great finding.

Comment: @enjoying - this I think will work better with more complex expressions and works fine without piping.

Comment: @enjoying - may be your workaround is related to [this IF bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28000194/why-if-checking-ignores-delimtersome-word-after-the-check-expression)

Comment: - It's interesting. Learned a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

For testing purposes the cmdcmdline variable can be used.
But this fails, when somewhere in the expression is a syntax error, as the complete code block will be dropped.

```
@echo off
echo dummy | (
echo %%cmdcmdline%
if 1 NEQ 2 echo Work
)
```

This results into `"2" can't be syntactically evaluated here` (From german `"2" kann syntaktisch an dieser Stelle nicht verarbeitet werden.`)

**So exactly in the case of a syntax error, you can't see the cause!**

I build a small debug variable for this case

```
@echo off
setlocal
(set \n=^
%=empty=%
)
set "debug=echo ### %%cmdcmdline%% ^) %%\n%%"
echo dummy | (
    %debug%
    if 1 NEQ 2 echo Work
)
```

When you add the `%debug%` you will see the cmdcmdline, but the code will not be executed, so you can examine how different modification take effect.

Like

```
...
| ( 
  %debug%
  break & if 1 NEQ 2 echo THIS FAILS
)
```

but

```
...
| ( 
  %debug%
  break ^& if 1 NEQ 2 echo This Works !!!
)
```

The trick is to add `^) %%\n%%`, this closes the debug expression code block with `)` and cancels further parsing of the remaing code by the linefeed `%%\n%%`.

Comment: so `break ^&if ...` is the ultimate workaround for this?

Comment: @jeb , It's coooool of your debug method. I tested `if 1234 gtr 124 echo ture`, `if 1234^ gtr 124 echo ture`, `if 1234^  gtr 124 echo ture` (The 3rd one has double SPACEs befor `gtr`. But the 2nd one is failed. Why?

Comment: @npocmaka, I think there is an even easier work-around that works with all `if` statements (including `not`, `exist`, `defined`, `else`, all comparison operators and on either side of the pipe): `(if^ left_item OP right_item ...)`

Answer (score 3):

Base on the idea & method from npocmaka & jeb.

Another way was found to solve the error of `IF` command in piped code.

**TO ADD AN ESCAPE SPACE AT RIGHT POSITION**

---

For `EQU` `NEQ` `LSS` `LEQ` `GTR` or `GEQ`,

1. **ONE** <kbd>^</kbd> has to be added after 1st compared `string/number`,
2. At least **TWO** <kbd>SPACE</kbd> have to be added between this <kbd>^</kbd> and `EQU` `NEQ` `LSS` `LEQ` `GTR` or `GEQ`.

Example,

```
echo pipe|IF 1234^  GTR 124 echo true
```

`true` can be replaced by `%^cmdcmdline%` to see the parser.

```
(IF 1234^  NEQ 124 echo right)|more
```

---

For `IF DEFINED` & `IF EXIST`

1. At least **ONE** <kbd>SPACE</kbd> has to be added after `IF DEFINED` or `IF EXIST`,
2. At least **TWO** <kbd>SPACE</kbd> have to be added before `variable` or `file/folder`,
3. **ONE** <kbd>^</kbd> has to be added between above added <kbd>SPACE</kbd>.

Example,

```
echo pipe|IF DEFINED ^  username echo true
echo pipe|IF EXIST ^  c:\windows echo true
```

`true` can be replaced by `%^cmdcmdline%` to see the parser

```
(IF DEFINED ^  username echo right)|more
(IF EXIST ^  c:\windows echo right)|more
```

---

**But so far I didn't know why all of them have to work like above.**

---

Something interesting,

```
echo pipe|if 123^   equ   ======  123 ======    echo %^cmdcmdline%
```

All <kbd>=</kbd> are ignored.

**Updated** (2016-04-23),

As npcmaka mentioned, `=`,`,` are also delimiters.

*CASE 1*

```
echo pipe|if not defined^===neq === echo %^cmdcmdline%
```

Outputs,

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe  /S /D /c" if not defined=== neq echo %cmdcmdline%"
```

*CASE 2*

```
echo pipe|if not defined^ === neq === echo %^cmdcmdline%
```

Outputs,

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe  /S /D /c" if not defined == = neq === echo %cmdcmdline%"
```

One space appears between `===`.

*CASE 3*

```
echo pipe|if not defined^,,,neq ,,, echo %^cmdcmdline%
```

Outputs,

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe  /S /D /c" if not defined,NEQ echo %cmdcmdline%"
```

Some phenomenon can be found, which may be known how to parse...

- `neq` is identified as variable in all *CASE*. (do `set neq=blah` before will occur no output for all *CASE*)
- In *CASE 2*, `==` in Delimiter `===` seems be **identified as comparison** and auto be added one space after
- According to the rule in *CASE 2*, in *CASE 3*, input `neq` is lowercase and output `NEQ` is uppercase. But in *CASE 1 & 2*, due to existed `==` before `neq`, this time, `neq` is kept in lowercase, which is not identified as comparison.

**So it has several steps in parser period. But has some bugs of adding or deleting delimiters. Right?**

*CASE 4*

The next code seems trigger `cmd` executing infinitely,

```
echo pipe|if not defined^ == echo %^cmdcmdline%
```

it runs like `if not "defined" == "echo" recursive command`

Comment: Yes.`=` is a standard delimiter in batch files - in a lot of cases it acts like `<space>`, `<tab>` , `,` ,`;`. This will also work `if 123 equ === 123 == echo #`

Comment: @npcmaka  - Something more interesting I found after reading your new post at dostips. please see my updated content...

Comment: Interesting.Looks like `cmdcmdline` is recursively expanded and executing itself.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest work-around to get `if` statements working within pipes is the following (the outer surrounding pair of parentheses is mandatory):

```cmd
(if^ comparison_expression conditional_command_line)
(if^ comparison_expression (conditional_command_line) else other_conditional_command_line)
```

I tested it with all keywords like `not`, `exist` and `defined`, `else` clauses, all possible comparison operators (`==`, `EQU`, `NEQ`, etc.), for either side of the pipe, and in `cmd` and batch-files.
Also I also successfully tested the `if` statements embedded within the body of a `for` loop (in which case the outer parentheses are no longer required).